# Programmatically narrow Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-tablelayout

I need to dynamically fill tables in my app and when I created the layout in XML I got the right result by messing around and making fields scale, but when I try to do so programatically I get this.

[image: The problem]

As you can see, the one which got cut off at the bottom was one that still got generated in XML and it matches the title bar perfectly.
The first three are added programmatically and aren't doing what they're supposed to do.

How do I get the Buttons to have no minimum width in code?

This is my row generation function:

```
private void generateLocationRow(){
    TableLayout tableLocation = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.info_table_locations);
    TableRow tableLocationTitleRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.info_table_locations_titles);
    LayoutParams params;
    //create counter for index in table
    int c = 3;
    for(Location l: locations){
        //makes Rows
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow(this);
        tRow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlueLight);
        tRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TableRow tDivider = new TableRow(this);

        //Makes 5 bottomBorders and puts them in an Array
        int bottomBorderCount = tableLocationTitleRow.getChildCount();
        View[] bottomBorders = new View[bottomBorderCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < bottomBorderCount; i++) {
            View bottomBorder = new View(this);
            bottomBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorDarkGray);
            int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); //converts dp to px
            bottomBorder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height));
            bottomBorder.setLayoutParams(bottomBorder.getLayoutParams());

            bottomBorders[i] = bottomBorder;
        }

        //makes 3 sideBorders and puts them in an Array
        int sideBorderCount = (bottomBorderCount / 2) + (bottomBorderCount % 2);
        View[] sideBorders = new View[sideBorderCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < sideBorderCount; i++){
            View sideBorder = new View(this);
            sideBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorDarkGray);
            int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); //converts dp to px
            sideBorder.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            sideBorder.setLayoutParams(sideBorder.getLayoutParams());

            sideBorders[i] = sideBorder;
        }

        //makes columnInfoButton
        Button btnInfo = new Button(this);
        LayoutParams paramsButton = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsButton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        btnInfo.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
        btnInfo.setMinHeight(0);
        btnInfo.setMinWidth(0);
        btnInfo.setText(R.string.info_button_info);
        btnInfo.setLayoutParams(paramsButton);

        //makes columnType
        TextView txtType = new TextView(this);
        params = new LayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        txtType.setLayoutParams(params);
        txtType.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        txtType.setText(String.valueOf(l.getType()));

        //makes columnName
        TextView txtName = new TextView(this);
        txtName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        txtName.setLayoutParams(params);
        txtName.setText(String.valueOf(l.getName()));

        //makes columnAddress
        TextView txtAddress = new TextView(this);
        txtAddress.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        txtAddress.setLayoutParams(params);
        txtAddress.setText(String.valueOf(l.getAddress() + " " + l.getTown()));

        //puts content in TableRow
        tRow.addView(sideBorders[0]);
        tRow.addView(btnInfo);
        tRow.addView(sideBorders[1]);
        tRow.addView(txtType);
        tRow.addView(sideBorders[2]);
        tRow.addView(txtName);
        tRow.addView(sideBorders[3]);
        tRow.addView(txtAddress);
        tRow.addView(sideBorders[4]);

        //makes divider
        for (int i = 0; i < bottomBorderCount; i++){
            tDivider.addView(bottomBorders[i]);
        }

        tableLocation.addView(tRow, c);
        tableLocation.addView(tDivider, c+1);

        c = c+2;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Bob Malooga Thanks for editing the title :p Couldn't find the word in my head.

Comment: I'm really impressed with the way you handled the border lines.  Thanks for sharing!